aiohttp.ClientSession http request stuck without error
I'm making async http request using aiohttp.ClientSession().
My code gets stuck at line where request is sent. No exception is raised. It just freezes.
Below is my code:
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
url = self.cfg['baseUrl']
async with (aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers, timeout=ClientTimeout(300)) as session):
    data = json.dumps({"data": ["a", "b", "c"]})
    try:
        print("before request")
        async with session.post(url=url, json=data) as response:
            print("after request")
            result = await response.json()
            print(result)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

Code prints out before request, after request is not printed out.
Code is stuck on async with session.post(url=url, json=data) as response:
Why this happens? How to correct my code so I can fetch json data from response?

Does the timeout occur after 5 mins? If so, then there's something wrong with your request or the server, it's not sending a response...

No, timeout doesn't occur. No exception, it just gets stuck.

Then you'll have to provide a full reproducer, because that definitely doesn't happen normally with the provided code.

Also, as a side point, you've passed a str to the json parameter, which will then be converted into a json string. Probably not what you wanted...
